# Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ProviderProps<UsersAction> | Readonly<ProviderProps<UsersAction>>): Provider<UsersAction>',

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm making a new application on Typescript with Redux and I got an error that was not clear to me (this is the first time I've encountered it), I've been racking my brain for an hour now. Maybe someone will be able to understand what the problem is or move their guesses.

[image]

and in the store I have actions and reducers

actions.ts

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {rootReducer} from "./reducers/index";

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

reducers.ts

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import {userReducer} from "./UserReducers";


export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

and even users.ts

```
import {UsersAction, UsersState, UserActionTypes} from "../../types/User";

export const initialState: UsersState = {
    user: [],
    isAuth: false,
    error: ""
}

export const userReducer = (state = initialState, action: UsersAction): UsersState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_ERROR:
            return {...state}
        case UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS:
            return {error: "", user: action.payload, isAuth: true}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from React 18, it [mandates that children be explicitly declared](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-typescript-definitions) as property. That's why it's complaining about `children` that don't exist.

You need to upgrade `react-redux` package to the latest version that [fixes this error](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56281) (At the time of this writing it's version 8.0.2). Or, downgrade React to version 17 or lower.